# Rails: How do I create a model with two "belongs_to" relations, one of which is always empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two separate models: "page" and "user".  I want to have a "comment" model that can comment on either a "page" or a "user", but not both at the same time.  I want to do something like this:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page
  belongs_to :user
end
```

but I'm not sure if that's the correct approach.  What's the best way to handle this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that what you need is [Polymorphic Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end


class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

And the migrations:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration   # and similar for Pages
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      ...
      t.references :commentable, polymorphic: true
      ...
    end
  end
end

class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      ...
      t.integer :commentable_id
      t.string  :commentable_type
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @NickM a comment can only belong to either a user or a page. The above makes it impossible for a comment to belong to both.

Comment: @NickM It does actually. The comment will only ever be associated with **either** the `User` or the `Page` at any given time, **but not both**.